# можно сделать в спринг секьюрити так, чтобы помимо информации о токене была и информация об юзере? как это сделать?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

можно сделать в спринг секьюрити так, чтобы помимо информации о токене была и информация об юзере? как это сделать? Как добавить эту информацию во внутрь токена? [image: A]

Comment: в общем кому интересно, могу рассказать)